# React Quadratic Calculator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, quadratic

I'm new to React and I am trying to build a simple quadratic calculator web app. There are three inputs for each variable, a, b, and c. No matter what numbers I put in the values returned are always NaN. Help would be much appreciated. Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      a: null,
      b: null,
      c: null
    };

    this.publish = this.publish.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange({ target }) {
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
  }

  publish(a, b, c) {
    document.write((-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / 
(2 * a) + "<br/>" +
    (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a));
  }

 render() {
 return( 
<div>
  <input
  type="number"
  name="Var A"
  placeholder="Enter Variable A"
  value={ this.state.a }
  onChange={ this.handleChange }/>

  <input
  type="number"
  name="Var B"
  placeholder="Enter Variable B"
  value={ this.state.b }
  onChange={ this.handleChange }/>

  <input
  type="number"
  name="Var C"
  placeholder="Enter Variable C"
  value={ this.state.c }
  onChange={ this.handleChange }/>

  <button value="Send" onClick={ this.publish }>Publish</button>
</div>
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use the Chrome Developer tools. Be sure to install the React Dev Tools plugin. Then read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips to debug your program.

Comment: Console.log() is your friend. :D It sounds like you might have some strings where you expect there to be numbers...

Comment: I suggest that you print the values of `a`, `b` and `c` in your `publish()` function. I think you will see that they are all `undefined`.

Comment: Note: You can do `-b` instead of `-1*b` to get the same result.

Comment: Try parsing the three values to integer or float.

Answer (score 0):

In the publish function you are using a,b and c which are passed as arguments, but what you actually want to use is the a,b and c from the state. 
Remove the argument from publish 
To look like :
```

```
  publish(){
             var a = this.state.a;
             var b = this.state.b;
             var c = this.state.c;

            ...


   }
```

```
Also the name of the inputs should be a, b and c and not Var A, Var B and Var C

This should fix you problem

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variable in state, but calling function with undefined parameters.

Try this:

```
publish() {
    var a = this.state.a, b=this.state.b, c=this.state.c;
    a = parseInt(a); b=parseInt(b); c = parseInt(c);
    document.write((-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a) + "<br/>" + (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2* a));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `target.name` in `handleChange` is not providing the expected value. The name assigned to your input is `Var a`.

`handleChange({ target }) {
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
  }`

`<input
  type="number"
  name="Var A"
  placeholder="Enter Variable A"
  value={ this.state.a }
  onChange={ this.handleChange }/>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the values of each input values properly, this can be done by using `setState`, but you have to properly set its name and value that will match to the `states`:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      a: "",
      b: "",
      c: ""
    };

    this.publish = this.publish.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
 console.log('change');
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  publish() {

   let a = parseFloat (this.state.a), b=parseFloat (this.state.b), c = parseFloat (this.state.c);
  let discriminant = (Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c));
  if(discriminant > 0){
  const root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    const root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
  document.write(root1+ "<br/>" +root2);
  }else{
   document.write('Discriminant is less than 0');
  }
 
   
  }

 render() {
 return( 
<div>
  <input
  type="number"
  name="a"
  placeholder="Enter Variable A"
  value={ this.state.a }
  onChange ={ this.handleChange }/>

  <input
  type="number"
  name="b"
  placeholder="Enter Variable B"
  value={ this.state.b }
  onChange ={ this.handleChange }/>

  <input
  type="number"
  name="c"
  placeholder="Enter Variable C"
  value={ this.state.c }
  onChange ={ this.handleChange }/>

  <button value="Send" onClick={ this.publish }>Publish</button>
</div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Also, if the discriminant is less than 0, it will output `NaN`.